# Java - Classpath issue

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I have a products.jar file. Inside that there is one class `com.ClassA`. The structure of the project is like

```
products
    |--test
        |--com
            |--ClassA.java
        |--dependencies
            |---inputs.txt
```

Inside eclipse, `ClassA.java` is accessing the `inputs.txt` file by the following path and it is working fine

```
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "test/dependencies/inputs.txt";
```

`test` package is in the java build path -> sources

But when I am exporting this project as `products.jar`, I find that in the jar file there is no `test` directory. There are two dirs `com` and `dependencies` at the root of the jar file. So when I am trying to execute the `ClassA` (residing in jar file) through command line, I am getting the following exception:

```
JUnit version 4.8.2
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test/dependencies/inputs.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
```

So after finding that `test` dir is not being exported in jar file, I changed the path of the file in my ClassA.java to `dependencies/inputs.txt`. It didn't work in eclipse but I thought that it would work in jar because jar file is in classpath and `dependencies` folder is at the root of the jar file so the java launcher will be able to locate the `dependencies` folder and then `inputs.txt` file.

But unfortunately it is also not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `FileInputStream` to read a file packed inside a JAR - it's not a file any more. `FileInputStream` only works for actual disk files.

You need to read the resource using `Class.getResourceAsStream` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)), e.g.

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dependencies/inputs.txt");
```

You leave off the `test` prefix because it's not in the JAR file structure.

Answer (score 2):

*FileInputStream()* will not read inside your jar, only files on the file system. Use *.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcename)* or *.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcename)*

More info on the javadocs for [class getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [classloader getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)